# Reading integers from a text file

Tags: java

I have a text file, in which I am writing 3 things

Eg < int,int,char> for each word.

Now, I am reading the file such that I consider a block of 3.1st one I always consider an integer, 2nd one also as integer and the 3rd one as character .There is no problem when the integer is from 0-9 but when it exceeds like 10,100 then my program doesn't work for the obvious reasons.

Like there is no problem when I have to read this

```
11a     here <1=int,1=int,a=char>
```

but when something like this comes, I face problem

```
152a    here <15=int,2=int,a=char>
```

I have put the whole text file in a string.Now, how how do I read the characters that I no longer face the above mentioned problem

Some more info: My text file contains characters like this
                 11a22d33f1234f

Comment: *"I have a text file, in which I am writing 3 things"* It seems a better way to approach deserializing the data is to serialize it in a more common and robust format - such as XML.

Comment: Show some code, specifically the stuff you have written to do the reading.

Comment: do you have any limit for the 1st or 2nd `int`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your current description of the problem, there is no way to determine if an entry such as

```
152a
```

corresponds to `(15,2,a)` or `(1,52,a)`.

Why don't you write to the file with some delimiter between elements, and then `split()` around the delimiter when reading back in from the file?

Comment: Good standart for such delimitation is the Comma-separated values format (CSV).

Comment: As basically I am compressing the data so using delimiters would further increase the size of the file but I guess I have to make use of delimiter

Comment: @Zara if the size if the main concern, why don't you save the file as binary, instead of text?

Comment: `15,2,a` is two characters longer than `152a`, and has the advantage of being absolutely unambiguous.

Comment: @JakubZaverka I am using an algorithm which requires me to save these three things <int,int,char>

Comment: Can you change that algorithm? Or is is a third-party algorithm that BINDS you to save int, int, char without any separators?

Comment: I think, I should make use of separators.

Answer (score 0):

your text file has improper format then
how do you want to differ  "1 11 a" and "11 1 a" e.g.
cant you use csv or something like that?